# How to create a dynamic formatter in SpringMVC based on user settings?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my application I have a class like this:

```
public class DateField {

  private String pattern;
  private Date date;

  public DateField(Date date, String pattern) {
    this.date = date;
    this.pattern = pattern;
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return this.date;
  }

  public String getPattern() {
    return this.pattern;
  }

}
```

The `pattern` is defined by the user and they can change it at any time using an admin interface without restarting the application.  I've read the [spring documentation on formatters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format) and I can't seem to see any way to have spring format the `date` based on the given `pattern` since the patterns are hard coded into the annotation.  I thought about implementing my own `Formatter` but I can only implement the `print` method because I don't have the `pattern` available in the `parse` method:

```
public class DateFieldFormatter implements Formatter<DateField> {

  @Override
  public String print(DateField dateField,
                      Locale locale) {
    if (dateField == null) {
      return "";
    }
    return new SimpleDateFormat(dateField.getPattern()).format(dateField.getDate());
  }

  @Override
  public DateField parse(String dateString,
                         Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    // I don't know what the pattern is here.
    return null;
  }

}
```

It seems like giving a user the ability to change a date format would be a pretty common use case so I must be missing something here.  How do I get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is dependant on user settings, you should store it in another object than the date field. IMHO, it would be better to have a `UserSettings` class, containing this date pattern, and a `UserSettingService` able to return the settings given a `Principal` extracted from the request or from a user id extracted from the `Session`.

Spring offers the possibility to access the current `Request` from anywhere in the application through `RequestContextHolder.currentContextAttributes()` provided you register a `RequestContextListener`. You can access the request that way :

```
ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes =
    (ServletRequestAttributes ) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
```

If you only need a session attribute :

```
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
String userId = requestAttributes.getAttribute("userid", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
```

With your example, you could use it that way :

The formatter injected with utility beans

```
public class DateFieldFormatter implements Formatter<DateField> {

    @Autowired
    PatternService patternService;
    @Autowired
    UserExtractor userExtractor;

    @Override
    public String print(DateField dateField,
            Locale locale) {
        if (dateField == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat(dateField.getPattern()).format(dateField.getDate());
        // or return new SimpleDateFormat(getPattern()).format(dateField.getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public DateField parse(String dateString,
            Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        String pattern = getPattern();
        DateField dateField = new DateField();
        dateField.setPattern(pattern);
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateString);
        dateField.setDate(date);
        return dateField;
    }

    private String getPattern() {
        return patternService.getPattern(userExtractor.getCurrentUserId());
    }
}
```

Some interfaces

```
interface PatternService {
    String getPattern(String userID);
}

interface UserExtractor {
    String getCurrentUserId();
}
```

Example implementations getting userId from a Session attribute or from Principal in Request

```
static class SessionUserExtractor implements UserExtractor {
    @Override
    public String getCurrentUserId() {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        return (String) requestAttributes.getAttribute("userid", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
    }
}

static class PrincipalUserExtractor implements UserExtractor {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentUserId() {
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes =
                (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
        return request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason the pattern and the date are stored together is because it's not a pattern for all dates in the application but just for this one in particular. Even if the objects were separated that still doesn't help with my question. How do I tell spring which pattern to use without hard coding it in the annotation?